# OneLogin redirect to an external link upon successful authentication

Tags: onelogin

I have OneLogin set up for SAML authentication for my application. A functionality of my application sends out notification links to users to take certain surveys. When a user clicks on the link it takes the user to the OneLogin page for authentication. Upon successful authentication the user is redirected to the default page of the application and not the survey page which the user is supposed to work on.
Current OneLogin setup has the Consumer URL set to the default.aspx page of my application. In the web.config I have added the One Login end point connector information.
Can anything be done in the OneLogin setup to cater to the above need? Or do we need to deal with this at the application level itself. Can we set up Rules in the RULES section of my application setup in OneLogin?

Answer (score 0):

To have this work properly you it sounds like you need to implement the relay state for SAML.

Essentially this value can function as a "deep link" within your application rather than the simple default page you have now.

This is usually implemented as part of SP-initiated SAML with a flow as follows

Send the user to your application - to the survey URL you want

Application doesn't have a session, starts an SP-initiated SAML flow to the provider (OneLogin) with a relay state set.

User authenticates, OneLogin does a SAML flow back to the app with the originally passed in Relay state.

Your app handles the SAML login and uses the relay state to direct the user to the original 'deep link' / relay state page.